# Linksys WAG54GS - Need to reserve IP addresses for WOL

Tags: firmware, wake-on-lan, adsl-router

I have a "Wireless-G ADSL Gateway with SpeedBooster WAG54GS ADSL router for my home in KSA, the stock Linksys firmware in it lacks lots of necessary features i.e MAC based QOS, DHCP IP reservation and so on which I am desperate for.

Basically I need a way to bind a MAC address to an IP address within this router (static ARP table) for some WOL purposes.  WAG54GS doesn't have this option (DHCP reservation) in the FW GUI, so I flashed a moded FW whcih has telnet enabled within the FW - where I need the proper command to "bind a MAC address to an IP address"

I'd be willing to use a custom firmware that has these features and it supports WAG54GS completely (including the ADSL part). I looked at DD-wrt and tomato, openwrt etc(supports everything except ADSL function) without any luck

My router specs are here

```
Linksys WAG54GS
Processor: Broadcomm BCM96348
Clock: 240 MHz Processor Bus: 133 Mhz-Reference: 33 Mhz
Bootloader: CFE 1.0.37-5.11
Flash: 4 MB
RAM: 16 Mb
Ethernet Switches: Broadcom BCM2535
Wifi: Broadcomm BCM4318 Car
```

Comment: I distinctly recall that WOL works purely via MAC addresses. A switched off system, even with a reserved IP address has no ip address.

Comment: That's Quite right  Journeyman Geek, my I need my router to statically remember the MAC address of my PC via either- DHCP reservation option or static ARP table - unfortunately Linksys WAG54GS does not have either function. So I installed a modem stock fimrware hoping to find the correct command line to bind MAC to IP - just to try and see, or a custom firmware that supports my Linksys WAG54GS totally- usually they have all the best features.

Comment: I need my router to statically remember the MAC address of my PC via either- DHCP reservation option or static ARP table - Linksys WAG54GS does not have either function in stock FW. So I installed a moded stock FW that is telnet enabled hoping to find the correct telnet line to bind MAC to IP - , or a custom firmware that supports my Linksys WAG54GS totally that normally has the ARP/DHCP advanced features. can't find either solution to MAKE my router rember my MAC.  The problem if i don't make it, the router purges the automatic arp/mac table once the PC off for LONG thus fail the WOL packets.